# Showing $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3^2+2i)=\frac{2^{n+5}\Gamma(n+\frac{11}{2})}{105\sqrt{\pi}}$

Tags: inner-products, gamma-function

Deduce the following equality:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3^2+2i) = \frac{2^{n+5} \Gamma(n+\frac{11}{2})}{105 \sqrt{\pi}}$$

So I have the product by expansion:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3^2+2i)=3^2(3^2+2\cdot 1)(3^2+2 \cdot 2)(3^2+ \cdots)(3^2+(n-1) \cdot 2)$$

I prefer to put this into binomial form, when doing so
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3^2+2i) = \binom{3^2+(n-1) \cdot 2}{3^2} \\ = \binom{\frac{3^2}{2}+(n-1)}{\frac{3^2}{2}} $$

Then in $\Gamma$ representation, I have the following
$$x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1) \\ \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3^2+2i) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3^2}{2}+n)}{(3^2/2-1)(3^2/2-2)(3^2/2-3)(3^2/2-4)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} \\ = \frac{2^4 \Gamma(\frac{3^2}{2}+n)}{105\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}$$

However, I am not deriving the same result.

Comment: Do you know  a value for $\Gamma(\frac12)$ ?  Something involving $\sqrt{\pi}$ ?  And can you relate $\Gamma(\frac92+n)$ to $\Gamma(n+\frac{11}{2})$ ?  Your denominator is the case $n=4$, which is why you got $2^4$ and not $2^n$.

Comment: You can do it faster considering the sum of the logarithms. Transforming the Pochhammer symbols into a gamma function gives the result almost immediately.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So I recognise $(3^2+(n-1)2)^{n-1}$ from the series expansion of the logarithm, can elaborate further on the logarithmic approach?

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar. It was useless but .... have a look at my answer

Comment: What a strange and beautiful formula!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the problem more general
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+b\,i)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} a\,\,\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+\frac{b }{a}\,i\right)=a^n \,\,\,\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+\frac{b }{a}\,i\right)$$

Using Pochhammer symbols and converting them in terms if the gamma function
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+c\,i\right)=c^{n-1} \left(\frac{c+1}{c}\right)_{n-1}=c^n\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{c}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}$$
Using $c=\frac ba$
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+b\,i)=b^{n-1}\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{b}\right)}=b^n\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}$$

For $a=9$ and $b=2$, you then have
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (9+2\,i)=\frac{2^{n+4}\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{9}{2}\right)}{105 \sqrt{\pi }}$$ which is not your result.

To obtain the rhs, you need $\large\prod_{i=0}^n$ and **not** $\large\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, wonderfully helpful! I have a question on the pochammer notation - can you expand this with an example, I cannot seem to understand the existing notation that you used

Comment: I think I now understand, so $\left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right)_{n-1}$ but to obtain the rhs, we have $\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)_n$ which becomes $c^n \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{c})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{c})}$?